# Navigating via the moderator flag bar always goes to questions

Tags: bug, flags, moderator-tools, waffle-bar

At some point the navigation arrows on the moderator flag bar changed to go directly to the question, even when the flag is on an answer, so it no longer jumps to the correct post anymore. For example, if answer ID 2 on question ID 1 has a flag, navigating to it via the flag overlay redirects to `/questions/1`, instead of `/questions/1#2` or `/a/2`.